# React: are nested attributes allowed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create an input component using React.js that would handle validation all on its own. However, I don't want to overshadow the existing JSX attributes, just to pass them along.

What I have right now is:

```
interface InputValidationRules {
  AllowEmpty: boolean,
  MaxLength?: number,
  MinLength?: number
}

interface InputComponentProps {
  LabelText: string,
  InputConfig: React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>,
  InputRules: InputValidationRules
};

const InputComponent = (props: InputComponentProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{props.LabelText}</label>
      <input {...props.InputConfig} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

My problem is: now I don't know how to create an InputComponent.
Ideally, it would be something along the lines:

```
<InputComponent
    LabelText="Hello"
    InputConfig={
      placeholder="World"
      disabled="true"
    }
    InputRules={
      AllowEmpty={false}
      MaxLength={12}
    }
/>
```

If you have any better alternatives on how I could implement this, I'm open minded; just point me in the right direction.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Syntactically you could pass it in as an object literal, but if this is the best fit for react it's hard for me to say. This will work: `<InputComponent LabelText="Hello" InputConfig={{ }} InputRules={{ AllowEmpty: false, MaxLength:12 }}/>`